# Empty row in dropdown admin panel magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, dropdown-attribute, option

I had empty row in drop down for attribute in adminpanel. Although there is no empy value while creating attribute.How to remove it.
[image]

Comment: this field create by ui component?

Comment: Yes Rakesh its from Ui component.